# when we need the property of dense

Tags: general-topology

In topology space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, a set $D$ is defined as dense set when cl$(D)=\Omega$. As I know from [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Topology.html), The main aim to use dense to try to find a countable subset $D$ which is dense in $\Omega$. For example, the subset of all rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the set of all the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: how to take advantage of the property of dense? or if $\Omega$ has a (countable) dense subset, what will happens?

Comment: It often suffices to show properties for dense subsets and then conclude that the property holds for the whole Space. This is for instance often used in functional analysis

Comment: @ DavidWallauch  is there any proof that "properties hold for dense subsets also holds for the whole Space"?

Comment: Well it depends on what you are doing. But for instance if u want to show that a linear operator is bounded it suffices to do so on a dense subset.

Comment: @DavidWallauch Just for confirmation, when we try to do this thing, are we usually try to work on the countable dense subset?

Comment: Well if there exists one. In a general a countable dense subset will not always exist

Comment: @DavidWallauch get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of useful things, two of them:

If $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space, the dual $X^*$ endowed with the weak-$*$ topology has the property that each compact subset $K$ is metrizable.

If $X$ is a metric space, and $m$ is a borel regular measure on $X$, then for each $A$ measurable with $m(A) < \infty$ and each $f:A \to S$ is mesurable, where $S$ is a seprable metric space, Lusin's theorem holds: for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a closed set $C\subset A$ with $m(A-C)<\epsilon $ such that $f$ is continuous on $C$

Comment: I know there should be many conclusions. But it is kind of fragmentation to check each thing. I want to know, when we prove them, are we firstly prove them works on the dense subset, and then proof them works on the whole space? Or else, I dont know why we need such a dense subset.

Comment: It depends, the crucial thing is that the dense set is coutable: being just a dense set is not a useful property, indeed if you have a topological space $X$, given a point  $x$, the set $D = X-\{x\}$ is dense in $X$ (unless the point $x$ is open). But this cleary isn't a really useful thing. The real feature is that you can select a countable set. This is a great feature when you need o work with "countable things" like series or $\sigma$-filels for example

Comment: That make sense. thank you. Seems that it is still hard to prove sth when the dense set is uncountable. is it useless when we can only find uncountable dense subset?

Comment: Absolutely no. But it may depend on the specific space you are considering: a general example is when you consider the completion $Y$ of a metric space $X$. If $X$ is not countable, $X$ will not be a countable dense subset of $Y$, but it is very useful to prove something for members of $X$ (which you know better how to handle) and then proceed by apoximation: for example this is crucial in the theory of Sobolev Spaces, which are completion of a certain class of smooth function under a certain norm: and smooth functions are easy to manage

Comment: get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

More examples:

(1).  First, a preliminary theorem: Let $Y$ be a $T_2$ (Hausdorff) space and let $X$ be any space. If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ are continuous then $\{p\in X: f(p)=g(p)\}$ is a closed subset of $X.$ (Not difficult. I think it is easier to show, equivalently, that $\{q\in X:f(q)\ne g(q)\}$ is open in $X$.)

An immediate corollary is that if $Y$ is $T_2$ and  the continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ agree on a dense subset of $X,$ then $f=g.$

For example if $f:\Bbb  R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ and $g:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ are continuous (with $m,n \in \Bbb Z^+$) and if $f, g$ agree on $\Bbb Q^m,$ then $f=g.$

This corollary  is also used in proving the Jones Lemma. A particular case (the smallest case) of the Jones Lemma is that if a separable space $X$ has a closed discrete subspace $Z$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$  then $X$ is not a $T_4$ (normal) space. For example the Niemitzky plane is not $T_4.$

(2). Theorem: If a metric space $X$ is separable then $X$ has a countable base (basis). Corollary: The topology of the Sorgenfrey line $S$ (which is the set $\Bbb R$ with the "upper-limit topology") cannot be generated by  a metric. Because it is easily shown that (i) $\Bbb Q$ is a countable dense subset of $S,$ and (ii) $S$ does not have a countable base.

Footnote: Re (2): If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $D$ is a dense subset of $X$ then $\{B_d(x,q):x\in D\land q\in \Bbb Q^+\}$ is a base for the space.